# Alignment issue in election nomination editor toolbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

There is an alignment issue in the election nomination editor toolbar.

I have verified the issue, it is exists in the following browsers:

- Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103
- Mozilla Firefox Version 47.0.1
- Internet Explorer Version 11.494.10586.0

[image: Nomination editor]

Comment: Are you going to nominate yourself or just went there for curiosity?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Just for curiosity. Also aware the nomination is going to close in few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have verified in the recent [2017 Moderator Election](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election/2) nomination page, the alignment issue was fixed.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Alignment issue is solved]